# How to write bool& operator[](int index) which returns reference to single bit

Tags: c++, operators

Lets look at very basic implementation of `Bitset`.

```
struct Bitset {
    bool mask[32];

    bool& operator[] (int index) {
        return mask[index];
    }
};
```

Now I can write

```
Bitset bitset;
bitset[0] = 1;
std::cout << bitset[0] << "\n";
```

There is possible optimization. I can use `unsigned int` instead of `bool mask[32]`.

```
struct Bitset {
    unsigned int mask;

    bool& operator[] (int index) {
        // ??
    }
};
```

Is it possible to write `bool& operator[] (int index)` with such specification ? I think `std::bitset` is doing something like that but i have no idea how.

Comment: `std::bitset` probably returns a sort of proxy object that known exactly what bit to poke.

Comment: If you know what code in STL should be doing what you want why not to look at the source?

Comment: Indeed: `Because no such small elemental type exists in most C++ environments, the individual elements are accessed as special references which mimic bool elements` (from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/). So `bitmap`'s `operator[]` returns `bitset::reference` and not a `bool`.

Comment: @Vlad, switch to cppreference.com, really.

Comment: @Griwes: sorry, cplusplus.com was first in my google results. :-P

Comment: @Alexei Lavenkov: Good point! I forgot that I can see actual source. I will look at it.

Comment: In case you're curious, you can find the STL bitset source [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bitset)

Comment: This is the `std::vector<bool>` conundrum: note that while you can make `operator[]` return a proxy object that does what you want, you'll never be able to write standard-conformant iterators for your collection class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't form a reference to anything smaller than `char`.

Instead, you could return an object that's convertible to `bool`, supports assignment, and knows which bit to read and write, along the lines of:

```
class bit_proxy
{
public:
    bit_proxy(unsigned & mask, unsigned bit) : mask(mask), index(index) {}

    operator bool() const {return mask & (1 << index);}
    void operator=(bool bit) {mask = (mask & ~(bit << index)) | (bit << index);}

private:
    unsigned & mask;
    unsigned index;
};

bit_proxy bitset::operator[](unsigned index)
{
    return bit_proxy(mask, index);
}

my_bitmask[3] = true;     // sets bit 3
bool bit = my_bitmask[3]; // gets bit 3
```

As noted in the comments, you might also want some compound assignment operations to more fully emulate a reference. You might also want a separate type, containing a `const` reference and no assignment operators, to return from a `const` overload of `operator[]`.

Comment: This is generally sufficient (and all I would probably do), but if you really want it to emulate `bool&`, you'd have to support `|=`, `&=`... and even `/=` (which is stupid, but `bool` supports it).

Comment: I think that the assignment operator should be `mask = (mask & ~(1 << index)) | (bit << index);`, otherwise assigning `false` to a bit that is set to `true` does not work.

Answer (score 5):

No, it isn't possible.  Bits inside a variable do not have unique addresses, so you can't form a pointer or reference to individual bits.

You will have to return a "smart reference" object instead of a raw reference.