# How to get a lvalue reference to a bit in std::bitset

Tags: c++

I was trying to do the following:

```
std::bitset<2000> a_bit_set{};
auto& a_bit = a_bit_set[5];
if (complicated_predicate(a_bit, other_params))
{
  a_bit.flip();
}
```

but clang complains:

```
non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::bitset<2000>::reference' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'std::bitset<2000>::reference'
```

I am suspecting this is because the `operator[]` is returning a rvalue rather than a lvalue here. But according to cppreference, there is a special class `std::bitset<>::reference` that should allow me to reference a particular bit in a bitset. My question is: **Can I get a lvalue reference to a particular bit in a bitset (aka`std::bitset<>::reference`)?**

Comment: Sooo, did you see the example section on that cppreference page with `std::bitset<>::reference`?

Comment: Related: [How to write bool& operator[\](int index) which returns reference to single bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144945/how-to-write-bool-operatorint-index-which-returns-reference-to-single-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get a lvalue reference to a bit in std::bitset

You don't. `std::bitset` doesn't contain any objects that represent an individual bit, and thus you cannot have a reference to such object.

> aka `std::bitset<>::reference`

`std::bitset<>::reference` isn't an lvalue reference. It is an object - a reference wrapper. The subscript operator returns that object as a prvalue. You can simply use a copy of that reference wrapper like this:

```
auto a_bit = a_bit_set[5];
```

Or you can use an rvalue reference which extends the lifetime of the prvalue:

```
auto&& a_bit = a_bit_set[5];
```

I wouldn't use the latter in this example since it introduces unnecessary complexity. But it can potentially be useful in some other cases that involve templates with a reference alias that may be either a true reference or a reference wrapper depending on template arguments.